# react.js map within map got unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const arr = [{class:"A", students:[{name:'james'},{name:'john'}]},
{class:"B", students:[{name:'janice'},{name:'xena'}]},
{class:"C", students:[]}]

    return (
      <div>
        {arr.map(outer => 
    (outer.students.map(person => <p>{person.name}</p>))
)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Got expected token using 2 map above, any clue? I want to build a UI like this

```
Class A - james, john
Class B - Janice, Xena
Class C
```

The challege is I can't display class C if the students object is empty.

Comment: You forgot a comma between the 2nd and 3rd `arr` array item

Comment: When using JSON and when you're getting unexpected token errors, most of the time it's because of invalid JSON. Use a validator like jslint to check for JSON errors first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That json is not a valid json, you missed `,` after class B object:

```
const arr = [
   {class:"A", students:[{name:'james'},{name:'john'}]},
   {class:"B", students:[{name:'janice'},{name:'xena'}]},
   {class:"C", students:[]}
]
```

To print the class name also you need to write it like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        {arr.map(outer => 
            <div key={outer.class}>
                {outer.class} -
                {outer.students.map(person => <p key={person.name}>{person.name}</p>)}
            </div>
        }
    </div>
);
```

Don't forgot to assign **unique key** to each element inside `map`.

Comment: but is my loop logic correct?

Comment: yes that part is correct, check the updated answer how to display class name also.

Comment: I got it. But my format is like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457023/react-js-map-did-not-render-content