# Map did not render content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<div>
    {!props.isLoading && <div>

        {normalizedData.map((outerObj,index) => {

            {
                <p className="space_name">
                    {outerObj.space_name}
                </p>
            }

            return(outerObj.applicants.map((obj,i) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            {renderDetail(obj)}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }))
        })}
    </div>}
</div>
```

For some reason I have to use `{}` and `return`, as I want to do some data manipulation in `map`, but somehow I did not see my `space_name` got rendered, but renderDetail is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

**1.** We can't return more that one element so wrap the all the elements inside 1st map in a `div`.

**2.** Use `return` inside 1st `map`.

**3.** Wrapping a `p` tag (any html element) inside `{}` is not required.

write it like this:

```
<div>
    {!props.isLoading && <div>
        {normalizedData.map((outerObj,index) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p className="space_name">
                        {outerObj.space_name}
                    </p>
                    {
                        outerObj.applicants.map((obj,i) => {
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        {renderDetail(obj)}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                    })}
                </div>
            )}
        )}
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I used your code, it worked but now my renderDetail doesn't render

Comment: renderDetails is a function, where you defined that function, inside render of outside? can you  show that function what you are returning from that?

Answer (score 2):

When you need to return multiple elements in a map you need to wrap all the elements in a single div in a return statement. So change the P tag to be in the return div.

```
<div>
    {!props.isLoading && <div>

    {normalizedData.map((outerObj,index) => {
        return(
            <div>
                 <p className="space_name">
                     {outerObj.space_name}
                  </p>

                  {outerObj.applicants.map((obj,i) => {
                      return (
                           <div>
                               <div>
                                   {renderDetail(obj)}
                               </div>
                           </div>)
                   })}
             </div>
     })}
     </div>}
</div>
```

Comment: this statement is not correct: **You cant render HTML in a .map() without the return.** we can render without `return`, like this: `<div>{[1,2,3,4].map(el => <p>{el}</p>)}</div>`, that return is required when we wrap the `map` body in `{}` then we need to `return` something inside body otherwise `return` is not required.

Comment: Edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way how you are using arrow functions. When you wrap it with `{}`, you need to return something. However when you wrap jsx with `()` it will return the content object directly, for example:

```js
const fn1 = () => {
  return { num: 1 }
}

const fn2 = () => ({
  num: 2
})

fn1(); // { num: 1 }
fn2(); // { num: 2 }
```

Therefore you can rewrite your code like this:

```
<div>
  {!props.isLoading &&
    <div>
      {normalizedData.map((outerObj,index) => (
        <div>
          <p className="space_name">
            {outerObj.space_name}
          </p>
          {outerObj.applicants.map((obj,i) => (
            <div>
              <div>
                {renderDetail(obj)}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: I can't do this way, I have to use return. As I said, I need to manipulate the data.